# Keep YouTube Vanced playing in the background when closing the mini-player

Tags: youtube

I'm using YouTube Vanced. When I close the picture-in-picture by tapping the "×" of the mini-player, the video stops and I have to click the play button in notifications to continue playing it in the background.

How can I make the video automatically continue seamlessly in the background?

**Environment**

- Android version: 9
- YouTube Vanced version: 16.29.39-Builds-01.54.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change **Settings** -> **Background & Downloads** -> **Playback** to **Always On**.

Then, while watching, it will just not stop when switching apps or returning to the home screen.

If Picture-in-Picture is on it will switch to the mini player, but tapping the mini player and then pressing the headphone symbol will switch to background/audio-only mode.

Tapping the X from PiP/mini player will always stop the video, even with these settings done properly.